# How to access the widget or the text of the button that was just clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I would like to add the button that was clicked to a list but i have no idea how to access the clicked button itself.

This is my [current list of Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxGGy.jpg).
Created through:

`for (var stand in stands) StandCreation(stand)`

This is the list i want to fill:

`List<String||Widget> SelectedStandList = []`

This is how i create each 'Button':

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class StandCreation extends StatelessWidget {
  final String stand;
  StandCreation(this.stand);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {}, // Here i would like to do something like SelectedStandList.add(tappedInkWell)
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 5,
          bottom: 5,
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(
          stand,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With the list i want then to create a new screen of only the selected items.
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ListView.builder` instead of `For` loop. change your `StandCreation` to this:

```
final VoidCallback onPressed;
StandCreation({this.stand, this.onPressed});
```

and change `onTap` to this:

```
onTap: onPressed
```

and finally change your For loop to this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 6, // how many buttons you want
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return StandCreation(stand: stand,
       onPressed:(){
            // Here is your onclick, do whatever you want with it  
        }
    )
   },
)
```

If you want each of your `onPressed` functions have different actions then you can simple put an `If` statement in there:

```
   onPressed:(){
        if(index==0) //do something with first button
    }
```